# How to control a view using NDK

Tags: android, android-layout, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm creating an Android app where I have a layout with FrameLayout which shows the camera stream and 2 images on top of it.

I need to be able to control the position of the 2 images using NDK. i.e - pass their position and instance to C++ code and allow it to move them around.

Also, when a Touch (and move) event is being called, I'd like to let C++ know about it and use it to move the images around.

I know I can pass the position parameter to the C++ code, but it is requested to pass the reference to the ImageView itself and allow the C++ code to control it.

Is it possible? if so - How can I allow a C++ code to control my views and layouts?

Many Thanks!

Comment: Using `JNIEnv` and reflected Java calls. There's no native (i. e. C friendly) view control interface.

Comment: How would I be able to reference the ImageView using the JNIEnv?

Comment: The question you should be asking is different: "how do I call Java methods from C?" Once you figure out that, you control your views using the very same method calls as if it was in Java. But from C. The answer to that question is - [read up on JNI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jni/spec/jniTOC.html). It's not a one-line topic.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Thank you :) Going to investigate that.